# SQL SUM of a Column in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a large table like below :

```
--------------------------
OrderNo     OrderQuantity
--------------------------
100             250.00
101             455.10
102              89.55
103             112.15
104             330.12
```

I have to filter by SUM of OrderQuantity by less than or equal to 800.00. My SQL query is below which did not work as expected.

```
SELECT OrderNo, OrderQuantity
    FROM WorkOrder
        HAVING SUM(OrderQuantity) <= 800
```

I expect a result like below.

```
--------------------------
OrderNo     OrderQuantity
--------------------------
100             250.00
101             455.10
102              89.55
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Took me a minute to understand this ... you want the "running total" to be less than or equal to 800, yes?

Comment: Yes. "running total" to be less than or equal to 800

Comment: I stumbled across your question via the "review queue" and didn't see that you already had responses. Looks like some of them will do what you want.

Comment: But none of the answers gave be expected result. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;With cte(OrderNo,OrderQuantity)
AS
(
SELECT 100,250.00 Union all
SELECT 101,455.10 Union all
SELECT 102, 89.55 Union all
SELECT 103,112.15 Union all
SELECT 104,330.12 
)
SELECT OrderNo,OrderQuantity From
(
SELECT *,SUM(OrderQuantity) Over( Order by OrderNo) AS SumOrderQuantity from cte
)Dt
Where Dt.SumOrderQuantity <=800
```

OutPut

```
--------------------------
OrderNo     OrderQuantity
--------------------------
100             250.00
101             455.10
102              89.55
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Although your sample has only `1` `orderno` per `orderquantity`, if you have multiple `orderno`, and you want to get the `sum`, use the below query.

```
SELECT OrderNo, sum(OrderQuantity)
    FROM WorkOrder
GROUP BY OrderNo
HAVING SUM(OrderQuantity) <= 800
```

So if you want to perform any `aggregated` calculations on a set of rows, you need `GROUP BY`

Comment: SELECT OrderNo, SUM(OrderQuantity) FROM WorkOrder WHERE OrderQuantity<800

Comment: Welcome. Read [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a correlated subquery to find the cumulative sum of the order quantity, and then restrict to only records where that sum is less than or equal to 800.

```
SELECT
    t1.OrderNo,
    t1.OrderQuantity,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.OrderQuantity) FROM WorkOrder t2
     WHERE t2.OrderNo <= t1.OrderNo) AS CumOrderQuantity
FROM WorkOrder t1
WHERE t1.CumOrderQuantity <= 800
```

Comment: This query doesn't run. `CumOrderQuantity` doesn't exist on t1.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing this in the wrong way , bad grammer  , when you're using a **having** clause ,you should **group by** the columns you want use in **having** clause,like this:
`SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value`
,try like this ,you may solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql sever 2012 or later you could do the following

```
SELECT OrderNo, OrderQuantity
FROM WorkOrder
Group By OrderNo, OrderQuantity
Having SUM(OrderQuantity) OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo) < 800
```

Comment: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."  Getting this error message :(

Comment: @kishork sorry have updated my answer the windowed function should be allowed in the having clause